# How to drop unset fields in protobuf response?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a message with multiple fields, but one of them isn't always set, how can I omit it in my response?

The field by default gets the null value but doesn't get omitted.

How can I omit the field and is it something I need to change in the proto or the cpp file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "omit"? Protobuf 3 already uses zero space in a serialized message to represent an unset field. And the generated message type is determined from the message definition, it doesn't vary based on the contents of the message.